# Rewind button in jwplayer

Tags: javascript, html, jwplayer

I have 4 video players on a page with the elements

video1
video2
video3
video4

i am trying to add a button that will rewind all 4 video players at the same time 30 seconds but its not rewinding here is the code any help or advice on what i did wrong would be greatly appreciated!

```
<input type="button" value="<-30" 
onClick="
var position = jwplayer('video1').getPosition(); position -= 30; jwplayer('video1').seek(position);
var position = jwplayer('video2').getPosition(); position -= 30; jwplayer('video2').seek(position);
var position = jwplayer('video3').getPosition(); position -= 30; jwplayer('video3').seek(position);
var position = jwplayer('video4').getPosition(); position -= 30; jwplayer('video4').seek(position);"
style="background:rgba(192,192,192,0.3);color:white;font-weight:bold" name="button2">
```

Comment: does it rewind one by one? or not rewind at all?

Answer (score 1):

Try having a variable for each player

```js
const players = [
  jwplayer("video1").setup({ ... }),
  jwplayer("video2").setup({ ... }),
  jwplayer("video3").setup({ ... }),
  jwplayer("video4").setup({ ... })
]
document.getElementById("rewind").addEventListener("click", () => {
  players.forEach(player => {
    let position = player.getPosition();
    position -= 30;
    player.seek(position);
  })
});
```

```html
<input type="button" value="<-30" id="rewind" style="background:rgba(192,192,192,0.3);color:white;font-weight:bold" name="button2">
```